# Compile Error: Cannot use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\True as True because 'True' is a special class name with php 5.6

Tags: php, symfony, php-7, php-5.6

I've run an application I'm working on on a newly created server. However, entering one of the pages I came across this error message: Compile Error: Can not use Symfony \ Component \ Validator \ Constraints \ True as True because 'True' is a special class name. I've read that this problem is related to the use of a symfony version not new with php 7. I then moved to php 5.6, but the same error messages appear. Can someone help me? How can i update symfony? I have tried with composer update and composer update symfony/symfony but don't work.

Comment: Anywhere in your code base are you using `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\True` instead of the updated validation constraints?

Comment: What version of symfony do you have set within your composer.json?

Answer (score 4):

So this really depends on your version of symfony, and what you have set within your composer.json.

If you are on a version prior to 2.7 it is PHP7 causing you grief, even if you think you've downgraded to 5.6 there's still the possibility you haven't done correctly.

On symfony 2.7 onwards the class in question has changed in order to avoid PHP7's reserved class names (True and False most appropriate to this situation), instead the equivalent classes are IsTrue and IsFalse, these are available from 2.7 onwards but only required if on PHP7.

If you check the Symfony2.7 documentation for True you will find this message.

> Caution
>
> The True constraint is deprecated since Symfony 2.7 and will be
>   removed in Symfony 3.0. Use the IsTrue constraint instead.

Within 2.7 and 2.8 you will still find the old classes alongside the new ones however the old ones will now have a depreciation notice.

I would advice your first action should be finding where you are calling these old validation constraints, probably within your Form types, possibly within your entities. When you find them simply swap them for the new IsFalse and IsTrue and you should be good to go.

> The following words cannot be used to name a class, interface or
>   trait, and they are also prohibited from being used in namespaces.

```
|                           |        **Reserved Words**                     |                       |
|-------------------------- |--------------------:  |--------------------   |---------------------- |
| int (as of PHP 7)         | float (as of PHP 7)   | bool (as of PHP 7)    | string (as of PHP 7)  |
| true (as of PHP 7)        | false (as of PHP 7)   | null (as of PHP 7)    | void (as of PHP 7.1)  |
| iterable (as of PHP 7.1)  |                       |                       |                       |
```

You can find the new list if reserved words here http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.other-reserved-words.php

Comment: How can i downgrade from php 7 to php 5.6?

Comment: That depends a lot on your operating system. There are many many guides out there for howto do it, if you get stuck after trying you should ask another question. **HOWEVER** you really should be trying to bring your code up-to date, not avoiding it. Just do a project search in your IDE for `Validator\Constraints\True` and it'll show you where you've used it.

Comment: This worked for me to downgrade PHP on Ubuntu 16.04 / Apache: https://askubuntu.com/questions/761713/how-can-i-downgrade-from-php-7-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04